# ¿Cómo generar una cadena aleatoria con 0's y 1's de gran tamaño en CoffeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Hola deseo generar cadenas para un algoritmo genético mediante coffesscript

He intentado con:

```
generate = (length) -> 
  Array.from(Array(length), () => `Math.random()<0.5?'0':'1'`).join ''

console.log generate(16)
console.log generate(16).length
```

Que me genera el siguiente código en javascript:

```
var generate;

generate = function(length) {
  return Array.from(Array(length), (function(_this) {
    return function() {
      return Math.random()<0.5?'0':'1';
    };
  })(this)).join('');
};

console.log(generate(16));

console.log(generate(16).length);
```

el código generado funciona en el navegador, sin embargo el código CS me arroja el siguiente error:

> TypeError: Object function Array() { [native code] } has no method 'from'

¿Existe alguna otra forma de lograrlo para digamos por ejemplo una cadena de tamaño 10000000?

Comment: [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/from) pertenece a ES6 de ahí el error que ves. Si te fijas el polyfill es enorme y probablemente ejecute mucho código que no necesitas. Tu algoritmo se puede generar con un simple ciclo for. Si te preocupa el performance debido a la inmutabilidad de los strings puedes crear un sparse array, llenarlo y luego hacerle `join`

Comment: y qué implica que pertenezca a ES6? CS es ES5?? en JS 10000000 creo que es mayor al número máximo aceptable por number, así que un for considero que no podría ser la alternativa ( pero tal vez con una respuesta pueda demostrarme lo contrario ).

Comment: Con lo del sparse array te refieres a algo como `Array.apply(null,Array(length)).map( ()=> ` Math.random()<0.5?'0':'1'`).join('')` ???

Comment: Yo compilé tu función con coffeescript y me funcionó bien. Lo que te explique anteriormente que podría no funcionar es cuando lo lleves al navegador ya que coffeescript siempre compilará a javascript y este último depende mucho del entorno en el que se ejecuta. La función que te comento es todavia experimental y puede ser la causa del problema. La recomendación es que no uses funciones experimentales. No he publicado una respuesta porque pones en tu pregunta que en el navegador te funciona bien por lo que no puedo reproducir tu problema.

Comment: ha intentado correrla desde la página oficial de coffeescript?

Comment: Sip y me funcionó tambien. Yo tengo Chrome 50 y Firefox 35. Cuando intentas con IE el error sale inmediatamente por las razones que te menciono.

Comment: Parece que se debe a la versión de CS que es 1.7.1, si gustas poner respuesta sería un gusto aceptarla :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda la cita de la documentación official de coffescript

> La regla de oro de CoffeeScript es: "Es sólo JavaScript". El código compila en su equivalente al uno por uno en JS, y no hay ninguna interpretación en tiempo de ejecución

Por lo que si tienes un error como estos lo más probable es que el código compilado sea el que te está dando error. Mirando tu código veo que usas [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/from) el cual [no es muy compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/from#Compatibilidad_con_navegadores) con la mayoría de los navegadores por lo que te recomiendo dos alternativas usando código un poco más estable.

La primera es simplemente generando caracteres en un ciclo while

```
generate = (length) -> 
   a = 0
   (`Math.random() > 0.5 ? '1' : '0'` while a++ < length).join ''
```

Que genera el siguiente código

```
var generate;

generate = function(length) {
  var a;
  a = 0;
  return ((function() {
    var results;
    results = [];
    while (a++ < length) {
      results.push(Math.random() > 0.5 ? '1' : '0');
    }
    return results;
  })()).join('');
};

console.log(generate(16));

console.log(generate(16).length);
```

La segunda es usando el constructor de Array(lenght) el cual te creará un [sparse array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) (o un arreglo con huecos) el cual es convertido a un ciclo al usar for..in ya que

> Las comprehensions expressions reemplazan (y compilan en) ciclos `for`

```
generate = (length) -> 
  (`Math.random() > 0.5 ? '1' : '0'` for num in Array(length)).join ''

console.log generate(16)
console.log generate(16).length
```

Que generará este otro código

```
var generate;

generate = function(length) {
  var num;
  return ((function() {
    var i, len, ref, results;
    ref = Array(length);
    results = [];
    for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
      num = ref[i];
      results.push(Math.random() > 0.5 ? '1' : '0');
    }
    return results;
  })()).join('');
};

console.log(generate(16));

console.log(generate(16).length);
```

Ambos te dan un resultado como este

```
0001001000101000 // aleatorio
16
```

Este código es compatible con cualquier navegador por lo que siempre te funcionará